# Ansible playbook - NPM Tasks are not running in parallel

Tags: ansible

I'm using Terraform to build AWS infra (100 spot instances) and Ansible to deploy some tasks on Ubuntu Linux (spot instances). In Ansible Playbook when I'm running `npm install` task (nodeJS), I see that only 5 machines are getting that task at the same time, then it continues to the next batch of 5 machines and so on. After 30 min Ansible is done performing the tasks.

Other tasks such as install service on machines goes fine which works in parallel.

```
- name: Wait 100 seconds, but only start checking after 5 seconds    
  wait_for_connection:    
    delay: 5
    timeout: 100

- name: Connect as jenkins slave - Create agent-label file       
  copy:
    dest: "/home/ubuntu/jenkins-swarm/run-jenkins-agent-label"
    content: AGENTS_LABEL_{{ job_name }}_{{ build_number }}                
  register: sout
#- debug: msg="{{ sout.stdout_lines }}"

- name: Connect as jenkins slave     
  shell: |    
    sudo service jenkins-agent start
    sudo service jenkins-agent status
  register: sout
- debug: msg="{{ sout.stdout_lines }}"


- name: Copy from S3 to FS (shared)     
  shell: /home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/.local/bin/aws s3 sync "s3://automationtool/{{ job_name }}_{{ build_number }}" "/home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/src_temp"    
  register: sout 


- name: NPM install source on FS (shared)       
  shell: |           
    cd /home/{{ ansible_ssh_user }}/src_temp
    sudo npm install          
  register: sout
- debug: msg="{{ sout.stdout_lines }}"
```

I expect to see that all the machines (~100) are getting the task on the same time, and execute it

Comment: To answer the question the code is not necessary, I think. You might want to properly [format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) the code, or delete the code from the question.

Answer (score 2):

To explain why you

> see that only 5 machines are getting that task on the same time, then continue to the next 5 batch and so on. after 30 min the ansible is done to perfom the tasks

let me quote from [Strategies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html#strategies):

> By default, plays run with a linear strategy, in which all hosts will run each task before any host starts the next task, using the number of forks (**default 5**) to parallelize.

Set serial in the playbook

```
- hosts: all
  serial: "100%"
```

> to see that all the machines (~100) are getting the task on the same time, and executed it.

Other options are available in [Delegation, Rolling Updates, and Local Actions](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation-rolling-updates-and-local-actions) and in [ANSIBLE PERFORMANCE TUNING](https://www.ansible.com/blog/ansible-performance-tuning).

Comment: Thanks for your comments, but this is still has poor performance, any other sugesstions, do u think that need also to update conf by the following keys ?  ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=30s
pipelining = True

Comment: IMHO, as a first step, move the controller into the "AWS infra". Ssh to the controller and run the plays from there. Test pipelining = True. Try [Mitogen](https://mitogen.networkgenomics.com/ansible_detailed.html). Test and experiment, YMMV.

Comment: i resolved it by adding parameter to ansible --forks=100 :) , thanks